# Is it possible to use typenames after an unpacked list as templates arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

In the most basic sense, I want to do this:

```
template<typename ... Args>
struct{
    typedef std::tuple<Args ..., int> myTuple;
}
```

But MSVC (in VisualStudio 2013) gives me quite a strange syntax error:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'int'
```

Is it possible to use a regular typename after an unpacked list as template arguments? If yes, how? If no, why not?

Comment: You should be able to do that. [It works in clang and gcc.](http://rextester.com/RUPJ81975)

Comment: MSVC is only partially up-to-date with C++11 and C++14 support.

Comment: Yeah, what version are you using? I use similar features on VS2013 and it works. (though I use a using statement...)

Comment: @Chnossos yeah I absolutely hate Microsoft for not being up to date in some regards. A lot of mechanisms are just not implemented. They still didn't add `noexcept`, and that's one of the easier features from what I can tell.

Comment: @iFreilicht: They polled devs asking what order they prefered, and I at least marked `noexcept` as a low priority.  Variadic templates and rvalues were at the top of my list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to use a regular typename after an unpacked list as
>   template arguments?

Yes, absolutely. You can insert arguments before and after a pack expansion in an argument list, and it is done exactly how you showed it. This is merely another example of how useless VC++ (or in this case, it's error messages) is when it comes to templates and recently introduces features.

By experimenting with an online compiler I found the problem to be the missing semicolon after the struct definition. For some reason the compiler error thus produced by VC++ refers to the tuple instead of the end of the struct. So, check for missing semicolons.

Comment: I think you wanted to declare `struct A`, not an Anonymous struct.

Comment: Kind of. The smallest self contained case works without a problem. But it also works without the workaround now, and it doesn't change that the bigger problem has the same issue, still. I'll do a bit of testing and let you know.

Comment: Upon further investigation, the issue I have provided seems to be non-existent. The problem lies somewhere else in the code. I have no idea why the case I provided didn't work at first, but it does now, as it was expected before. The issue I'm facing is still about templates, but I will post a new question for it. Thank you!

Comment: @iFreilicht Lol - just realized that the error message in the OP only pops up if you forget to end the definition of the struct with a semicolon. Should i update the answer? :o)